# React Router 4 + Redux 5 Actions not passing to Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react project using react-router 4 and redux 5
if i make a simple axios request i can receive data but when trying to pass it to the reducers i get the reducer call back but without the data from the action nor do i see it in my store. so i am trying to figure out how to receive that data back. in the console log i get back 2 messages from the reducer. the firt is `@@redux/INIT` and the second is: `@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_1.d.5.t.z.5`

index.js:

```
  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// Redux
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'; // Redux Dev Tools for Chrome
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// Redux Promise Middleware
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

// Redux Thunk Middleware for Action Creators
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// React Router 4
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import reducers from './reducers';

// import configureStore from './reducers/configureStore';
// const store = configureStore();

const history = createHistory()
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)

const store = createStore(combineReducers({...reducers, router: routerReducer}),
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware(),thunk)));


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.js (rootReducer)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import adverts from './adverts_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  adverts,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducer file:

```
import { FETCH_ADVERTS } from '../actions/adverts_action';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  console.log('Reducer found', action);

  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_ADVERTS:
      return {
        adverts: action.payload.result,
        ...state
      };
  }
  return state;
}
```

action file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const ROOT_URL = `https://somecoolurltopullin`;

export const FETCH_ADVERTS = 'FETCH_ADVERTS';

export function fetchHomepageAdverts() {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/images/`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('Action Request:', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_ADVERTS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

EDIT:

actioncreator:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const ROOT_URL = `urlhere`;

export const FETCH_ADVERTS = 'FETCH_ADVERTS';

export function fetchHomepageAdverts() {
 const url = `${ROOT_URL}/images`;
 return function (dispatch) {

     const request = axios.get(url)
     .then(result=>{
          console.log('Action Request:', request);

          dispatch({
             type: FETCH_ADVERTS,
             payload: request
          });
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          // handle the err
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing the disaotch on your actions file, after you execute the api method you should **dispatch** the result to the reducers.
in your reduce you use the name: FETCH_ADVERTS.

please add dispatch before you return the response

```
import axios from 'axios';

const ROOT_URL = `https://somecoolurltopullin`;

export const FETCH_ADVERTS = 'FETCH_ADVERTS';

export function fetchHomepageAdverts() {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/images/`;
  return function (dispatch) {

     const request = axios.get(url)
         .then(result=>{
              console.log('Action Request:', request);

              dispatch({
                 type: FETCH_ADVERTS,
                 payload: result
              });
          })
          .catch(err=>{
              // handle the err
          })
  }
}
```

with that change i also recmoended to make your api action async and the dispatch method on the return of your api get respone, something like that:

```
api.getData().then(rsult=>{
 dispatch({type: FETCH_ADVERTS,payload: request});
})
.catch(err=>{
// do something for err handling
})
```

if it help you please vote
Thanks Hod

Comment: in the action creator i am getting the error message that 'dispatch' is not defined

Comment: i just update the answer with the add of the dispatch before the api call, check it out

Comment: just edited main post, changed it to this this format which i used before but still didnt get results but its removed the error message and there are no errors now but no data

Comment: swapped over to the one you rewrote, no errors but no data returned

Comment: in the reducer action: should be action.payload.result

Comment: updated the reducer file to action.payload.result but still no luck

Comment: got a error in the reducer now saying unreachable code

Comment: put debugger and check what you got

Comment: i update the answer, also in the action change the dispatch line

Comment: still have the Unreachable code error. could this be an issue in the index.js file when setting up the store? looked around online but no luck